# How can my c++ code which i wrote using gedit send commands to my terminal using Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, terminal, gedit

I have this security assignment in which I'm supposed to encrypt a file using `aes-256-cbc`. I'm suppose to write this code using `C++` on gedit. but to make the code easier we are allowed to use the `openssl` package which is already installed with linux. However, my doctor would like us to automate this operation. I know that if I write in my C++ code the following line

```cpp
system("openssl aes-256-cbc -a -in plain.txt -out plain.enc" )
```

I will get the terminal to ask me to write the key to my encryption algorithm. But my key is also supposed to be sent to my terminal. I tried adding a second line of code

```
system("and placing my password here")
```

but it seems that the terminal thinks this is another command. I also tried including it with the first system command like

```cpp
system("openssl aes-256-cbc -a -in plain.txt -out plain.enc"&"password" )
```

but this isn't working either. I'm new to linux Ubuntu and all of this so please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt, and show it to us in the question. And lastly, please try to write text that is easier to read, a "wall of text" (lik in your question) is very hard to read and understand. Add paragraphs and spacing.

Comment: There is a C API to openssl. Use it instead of trying to execute a shell command with `system("...")`. See the [wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) for more information.

Comment: As Far As I Know, using `std::cout` sends stuff to the terminal.  Have you tried it?